# What is a Tensor kernel in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, tensor

What is a Tensor kernel in machine learning? What is the difference between Tensor kernels with common kernels like RBF kernel?
When tensor kernels are used and what their advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a semantic issue. A Kernel is an encapsulated function.
In order to apply it to a data-tensor we need to convert the kernel to a tensor shape, but in the end  it is still the same function.

- [Understand tensors](https://medium.com/data-science-bootcamp/understand-tensors-and-matrices-2ea361e303b8). They "are just high dimensional matrices".
- [Understand ML Kernels](https://www.educba.com/kernel-methods/). Basically a kernel is an encapsulated function. The kernel trick is used to pass a linear function over a (none-linear) kernel or filter, in order to achieve a complex none-linear function in a less complex way. This allows a linear function learning none-linear features, saving a lot of computational power, since
  using a polynomial function can become too expensive for large (or complicated) datasets training. I.e., we can compute linear functions using none-linear kernels to learn none-linear patterns.

So, RBF is represented as a tensor kernel (exponential gaussian kernel), but this is just the most popular kernel in machine learning to learn none-linear representations (specially used in SVM).
[SVR using linear and non-linear kernels](http://sigmaquality.pl/uncategorized/support-vector-regression-svr-using-linear-and-non-linear-kernels-en240120201439/).

There are other tensor kernels that you could use instead, like the Sigmoid Kernel or the polynomial kernel.